# JW player not working on the server

Tags: jwplayer7

I am using same JWplayer key for both localhost and the server. It is working absolutely fine in the local. But on the server side I am getting the following error.

```
Jw player missing license key
```

Please correct me if I am asking anything wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer this without seeing your embed code, but you if you are self-hosting our player, you need to define jwplayer.key after you load the player library but before you call jwplayer().setup().

Please see http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406723-mp4-video-embed for more details.